# Can 7-Zip store the final archive to a custom path on a different partition?

Tags: compression, 7-zip

I have a folder "D:/Tutorials/Exercise files"
I want to compress "Exercise files" folder and put it on E:/Tutorials/ folder, that is on drive E: automatically from within the 7-zip program.

Does 7-zip have this ability? To compress and store the final archive to a custom path on a different partition ??

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU expect some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: my research has shown nothing relevant (since I used the set "different path" in the keyword tail and it pointed to other irelevant posts for my situation)

Comment: Then you need to state that in your question so we know you have done some research. Please Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  7-zip has this ability to compress and store the final archive to a custom path on a different partition:

[image]

Comment: I think the key word is "Automatically", or by default.

Comment: @Moab I guess you're right but it's really unclear, I leave it for Google.

Comment: "put it on E:/Tutorials/ folder, that is on drive E: **automatically** from within the 7-zip program." its clear to me.

Comment: @Moab The OP wrote three times the question: automatically appears in only one of them.

Comment: This is a pissing contest, the question is clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not using the GUI, but you can do that using command line parameters.

For example :

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -t7z -mx9  d:\output_file.7z  f:\inputdir\*.*
```

Where

- "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" is the path on your computer of the 7z executable...
- a means archive
- -r means recursive inclusion of the files
- -t7z means output to 7zip format
- -mx9 set to ultra compression

It's then easy to automate it (save this line in a batch file, and then add a shortcut in startup menu, or add it to the Task Scheduler)